# Окрасить ячейки datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

имеется вот такая таблица Datagrid
[image: расписание]

Ячейки на данный момент окрашиваются  конвертером

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var x = value;
        if (x.ToString().Contains("ночь"))
        {
            return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
        }
        else if (x.ToString().Contains("день"))
        {
            return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightYellow;
        }
        else
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

и конвертер привязан к таблице стандартно вот так :

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Content.Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsPivotalEntryToColorConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>                        
                    </Style>
```

Данные для формирования итоговой таблицы собираю в сводную таблицу а потом в DataTable привязываю их вот так

```
DataView buf = newDt.DefaultView;
        Schedule_table.ItemsSource = buf;
```

Собственно вопрос: 
Как я могу избавиться от слов "день" и "ночь" ,не потеряв при этом окраску фона ячеек?

Я перепробовал кучу вариантов и даже записывал в DataTable не строки а объекты содержащие номер и время суток но тогда GridView выводит в ячейки не номер а название объекта в духе "PivotTable.CWrapper"

**UPD.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <DataTemplate>
   <Grid Background="{Binding DataContext,Converter={StaticResource IsPivotalEntryToColorConverter}}">
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
```

переделал как советовали в комментариях,результат выше.
при этом DataTable Заполнен вот такими объектами 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сами привязали Background к текстовому Content.Text, для чего у вас нужен стал конвертер со слов "день/ночь" в цвет. Так привяжите Background к чему нибудь другому что тоже отображает день/ночь (например простой булевый флаг IsDay или перечисление)

Comment: @vitidev я пробовал заполнять Datatable объектами которые содержали 
строку со значением и флаг c временем суток,  тогда в Datagrid выводится название объекта а не его содержимое
т.е если я создал объект

 
public class CupWrapper
{
public string cup;
public bool IsDay;
}
и заполнил им таблицу , то я увижу во всех клетках "CupWrapper".
мне нужно как то опуститься на уровень ниже и достать CupWrapper.Cup
но как это сделать я не знаю. и я не могу использовать строгий биндинг столбцов 
т.к количество столбцов мне заранее неизвестно

Comment: Похоже вы используете автогенерацию столбцов. А попробуйте заменить "{Binding Content.Text" на "{Binding DataContext"  - по идее так в ваш конвертер должен попасть сам объект данных CupWrapper

Comment: @vitidev переделал как вы сказали , результат в посте.

Comment: Как только вы ввели CupWrapper вместо строки, то в ячейках стал отображаться CupWrapper, ведь там делается ToString() Чтобы его правильно отобразить вам нужно определить CellTemplate, но у вас AutoGenerateColumns="True" для которого нужно реализовать обработку события AutoGeneratingColumn в коде и там же лепить шаблон.....или же можно попробовать переопределить ToString() у CupWrapper для фикса отображения сложного объекта в ячейке.

Comment: @vitidev добавьте ответ ,чтобы я мог лукас поставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно я решил указанную проблему,спасибо @vitidev за то подтолкнул к поискам!
Сейчас таблица выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я переписал код из этого поста https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643765/wpf-datagrid-databind-to-datatable-cell-in-celltemplates-datatemplate/25652728 под свои нужды

Решение в моем случае выглядит так :

Сначала создаем словарь с DataTemplate в XAML коде нужного нам окна

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DataRowViewConverter x:Key="drvc" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CupCell">
        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell}, Converter={StaticResource drvc}}" Text="{Binding Path=Cup}" Background="{Binding Path=DayOrNight}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Далее я изменил класс которым заполнял DataTable так ,чтобы в нем хранилась непосредственно кисть для заднего фона:

```
public class CupWrapper : DependencyObject
    {

        private string cup;

        private SolidColorBrush dayOrNight = new SolidColorBrush();

        public string Cup
        {
            get => cup; set => cup = value;
        }
        public SolidColorBrush DayOrNight { get => dayOrNight; set => dayOrNight = value; }
    }
```

Мне сложно понять что делает конвертер DataRowView т.к его я взял из поста на который указывал ссылку.Возможно дополню это позже когда разберусь до конца. 
Его код вот такой:

```
public class DataRowViewConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = value as DataGridCell;
        if (cell == null)
            return null;

        System.Data.DataRowView drv = cell.DataContext as System.Data.DataRowView;
        if (drv == null)
            return null;

        return drv.Row[cell.Column.SortMemberPath]; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Ну и самое главное. Вешаем на наш DataGrid обработчик события AutoGeneratingColumn.
Вот его код:

```
private void DgMain_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, 
  DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTemplate dt = null;

        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(CupWrapper))
            dt = (DataTemplate)Resources["CupCell"];

        if (dt != null)
        {
            var a = dt.Resources;
            DataGridTemplateColumn c = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
            { 
                CellTemplate = dt,
                Header = e.Column.Header,
                HeaderTemplate = e.Column.HeaderTemplate,
                HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
                SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName // this is used to index into the DataRowView so it MUST be the property's name (for this implementation anyways)
            };             
            e.Column = c;
        }
    }
```

Еще раз огромное спасибо @vitidev и @J.H(С английского SO)